# Prove that $(4^p+1)/5$ is a composite integer for $p$ a prime greater than 5.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

So far I have found that $(4^p+1)/5=\sum_{n=0}^{p-1} (-1)^n4^n$, not sure where to go from here. Was thinking about trying to find some base for which $(4^p+1)/5$ is not a pseudoprime but have had no luck.

Comment: $p=5$ also works. But for $p>5$ it is always a strong
pseudoprime to base $2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As $p$ is odd:

$$ 4 x^4 + y^4 = (2x^2 + 2 xy + y^2)(2 x^2 - 2xy + y^2)   $$

Taking $$ t = \frac{p-1}{2} $$
we have $$ x = 2^t, $$
$$ x^2 = 4^t $$
$$ x^4 = 4^{2t} = 4^{p-1}, $$
$$ 4 x^4 = 4^p. $$
Then take
$$ y = 1. $$

Comment: Beated in time, great Will

Comment: I read a comment from the phone some hours ago, but I was in hurry.. I hope everything's fine there ;)

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti, right, I'm in California. The matches from the English Premier League are often on at 7 AM Pacific time, so I got up a little early in hopes of seeing one; during the winter holidays, England has about four matches per team, while most European leagues take a break. The bad news is that the holiday matches start on the 26th, called Boxing Day in England. So, not much to see today.

Comment: Holidays should be holidays, enjoy your free time at least now :) Unless you really think it's worth it.. I wish you a good Christmas

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti Merry Christmas. Note that, while England are probably going to have many football matches during the holidays, Sir Alex Ferguson made the reasonable suggestion that they arrange  time off for the league players, maybe later in January or in February, time for injured players to heal and so on.

Comment: Thanks :) Have fun with these football matches and relax!

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti  having a relaxing day. Here is a new article about the schedule in England, written for an American newspaper http://www.nytimes.com/2016/12/23/sports/soccer/premier-league-christmas-boxing-day.html

Comment: I am happy to read it, even if I am not really a football fan :P Here we are just eating (too) much..

Answer (score 6):

Set $x=\frac{1}{2}(p-1)\ge 2$, then
$$
1+4^p=(1+4\cdot 2^{4x}+2^{2x+2})-2^{2x+2}=(1+2^{2x+1}+2^{x+1})(1+2^{2x+1}-2^{x+1}).
$$